# Logarithm of sum

Tags: logarithms

I have an equation of the form:
$Y = A + A*e^{-b_1}+A*e^{-b_2}+A*e^{-b_3}+...+A*e^{-b_n}$.

I want to get rid of the exponential term. So, I am thinking of using a logarithm on both sides. It will help me to use geometric/arithmetic series for the summation of the $b_1, b_2, b_3,...,b_n$. Then I want to take antilog to get the original term. Can someone please help me to find the logarithm of the sum of the above equation? Thank you.

Comment: There aren't any nice transformations for the logarithm of a sum.

Comment: What is the unknown ?

Comment: Is there any property of logarithm that we can use to simplify the logarithm of the sum as described in RHS of the above equation?

Comment: You can write it as $\ln(A) + \ln(1+e^{-b_1} + ... + e^{-b_n})$. You cannot simplify further.

Comment: Thank you for comments. I would appreciate if someone can provide more tricks.